# How to go from a single view to a tab bar view

Tags: ios, uiview, xcode4, uitabbar

need some help here
My problem is, my app starts with a single view, it shows a menu made with buttons that takes me to different places, one of this places is another kind of menu, but this menu is a tab bar menu, so the thing is, I made a new file with its .xib, I added the tab bar controller, and i Linked all the sections of my tabs with its viewcontrollers...
this means that I have my first menu ready, I have my view controllers ready, I have my menu on the tab bar ready.... 
so my problem is...
how can I go from my single view (the first view that I see and that doesnt include a tab bar), to the new screen with tab bar controller in it after pressing a button???

help me please

Note: I'm using XCode 4.2 and I'm not working with storyboards (requirements of the app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three options to show your viewController content :

1.using `presentModalViewController:`

2.add the viewController view as a subView to the current viewController. in your case : `[singleViewController.view addSubView:tabBarViewController.view];`

3.or if your simple ViewController is the navigation root viewController you can push other viewControllers to its navigation stack. (as @roronoa zorro described).

Comment: I actually used the second option, the project owner doesnt want a modal for that part
Thank you a lot, you gave me different options

Answer (score 1):

You might have added all the next viewControllers on the taBarController so if you have want to tabbar on to next screen you simplr have to push the tabbarcontroller on the navigationcontroller.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:TabBarControllerObj];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I tried, but @Malek_Jundi gave me more options, anyway thanks for your help :D